# install GRUB onto a CD

Tags: linux, dvd, grub, compact-disc, bootloader

I have got about 10 Linux installation ISOs. I want to put them all onto 1 CD/DVD, so that when the CD/DVD gets booted, it will give me a GRUB menu asking which Linux I want to install.

How do I do this? How do I install GRUB onto a CD?

Answer (score 5):

- If you want to do it off a USB: [How To Boot 10 Different Live CDs From 1 USB Flash Drive - How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39747/how-to-boot-10-different-live-cds-from-1-usb-flash-drive/)
- For a DVD/CD: [MultiCD](http://multicd.tuxfamily.org/) or [XBoot: Put multiple utilities/Linux distros/disc-based AVs on one bootable CD/DVD/USB drive | dotTech](http://dottech.org/freeware-reviews/20053/xboot-put-multiple-utilitieslinux-distrosdisc-based-avs-on-one-bootable-cddvdusb-drive/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use grub on a CD/DVD, use syslinux (isolinux) project: http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/The_Syslinux_Project